# Store switcher not showing in frontend magento 2

Tags: frontend, magento-2.1.3, store-switcher

I have created a new website store and store view in magento 2.1.3 backend and configure the new site language but i can't see the store switcher in frontend

Here is my back end setup
[image]

heare i selected English as default for Indian store and Arabic for Arabic store

And i need to display like below image in frontend 
[image]

Comment: Can you show us your store setup please? And what you have done to try and resolve the issue, such as clearing cache.

Comment: @ Ben Crook please look at the updated data

Comment: Thanks @Amith - I've added an answer, can you let me know if that helps please

Comment: @Ben Crook  can we add language selector like this? not store view i mean like google language transulator

Comment: I'm not sure, if you take a look at https://translate.google.com/manager/website/ it should give you an idea. But I think the best way is to use Magento's translations.

Comment: I've just read this which makes me think Google's translate isn't very safe for ecommerce sites: "The connection it uses to send the page for translation won’t be secure."

Comment: I have this situazion -Website
-------Indian Store Indian Store View
--------Arabic store Arabic Store View But store switcher not displaied with my website with porto theme. How can i do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you have created two websites, for the store switcher to display you need at least 2 store views under the website.

So you should have it configured like this:

- Website

  - Indian Store

    - Indian Store View
  - Arabic store

    - Arabic Store View

---

Or if all your data (e.g products, user sessions, payment gateways) are the same you could do this:

- Website

  - Store

    - Indian Store View
    - Arabic Store View

Comment: i can't see select store on frontend.